# Compiling Qt 5.3.2 + VS2008 + SDK7.1 error SHARDAPPIDINFOLINK

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2008, qt5

When  compile `Qt 5.3.2 + VS2008 + SDK7.1` I got these error:

```
qwinfunctions_p.cpp
qwintaskbarbutton.cpp
qwintaskbarprogress.cpp
windowsguidsdefs.cpp
qwinjumplist.cpp
qwinjumplistcategory.cpp
qwinjumplistitem.cpp
qwineventfilter.cpp
qwinthumbnailtoolbar.cpp
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\include\shlobj.h(2947) : error C2011: 'SHARDAPPIDINFOLINK' : nueva definición del tipo 'struct'
    c:\qt\5.3.2\qtwinextras\src\winextras\winshobjidl_p.h(228) : vea la declaración de 'SHARDAPPIDINFOLINK'
.\qwinjumplistcategory.cpp(134) : error C2079: 'info' utiliza struct 'SHARDAPPIDINFOLINK' sin definir
.\qwinjumplistcategory.cpp(135) : error C2228: el operando izquierdo de '.pszAppID' debe tener class/struct/union
    el tipo es 'int'
.\qwinjumplistcategory.cpp(136) : error C2228: el operando izquierdo de '.psl' debe tener class/struct/union
    el tipo es 'int'
.\qwinjumplistcategory.cpp(137) : error C2228: el operando izquierdo de '.psl' debe tener class/struct/union
    el tipo es 'int'
.\qwinjumplistcategory.cpp(139) : error C2228: el operando izquierdo de '.psl' debe tener class/struct/union
    el tipo es 'int'
.\qwinjumplistcategory.cpp(139) : error C2227: el operando izquierdo de '->Release' debe señalar al tipo class/struct/union/generic
qwinthumbnailtoolbutton.cpp
qwinevent.cpp
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN\cl.EXE"' : código devuelto '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN\nmake.exe"' :     código devuelto '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cd' : código devuelto '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cd' : código devuelto '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cd' : código devuelto '0x2'
Stop.
```

This error was reported in: https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-36037

I follow these instruction: -change line 223 on C:\Qt\5.3.2\qtwinextras\src\winextras\winshobjidl_p.h:

```
    #if (defined _MSC_VER && _MSC_VER < 1600) || defined(Q_CC_MINGW)
```

to

```
    #if (defined _MSC_VER && _MSC_VER < 1500) || defined(Q_CC_MINGW)
```

and it solve it but I don't know if is the correct solution :S