# how to build Qt5 with qtwebkit on Windows with MSVC 2008 - leveldb can't find stdint.h

Tags: windows, build, qt5, leveldb, stdint

On a Windows 7 x64 box:

- I installed [Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7 and .NET Framework 3.5 SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3138)
- I downloaded and unzipped Qt5.4.0 source from the "Source packages and Other releases" section of http://www.qt.io/download-open-source/#
- I built `ICU 54.1` from source and installed it, per http://qt-project.org/wiki/Compiling-ICU-with-MSVC.
- I created a command prompt shortcut per http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-building.html.
- I added stuff to the command prompt per http://qt-project.org/wiki/Building_Qt_5_from_Git and the Usage section of http://qt-project.org/wiki/Compiling-ICU-with-MSVC.

So my qt5vars.cmd is:

```
CALL "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\bin\vcvars64.bat"
SET _ROOT=C:\qt\qt540
SET PATH=%_ROOT%\qtbase\bin;%_ROOT%\gnuwin32\bin;C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Scripts;%PATH%
REM Uncomment the below line when using a git checkout of the source repository
REM SET PATH=%_ROOT%\qtrepotools\bin;%PATH%
SET QMAKESPEC=win32-msvc2008
SET PATH=%PATH%;C:\icu\dist\lib;C:\Ruby193\bin
SET INCLUDE=%INCLUDE%;C:\icu\dist\include
SET LIB=%LIB%;C:\icu\dist\lib
SET _ROOT=
```

- I updated `qtwinextras\src\winextras\winshobjidl_p.h` per [Compiling Qt 5.3.2 + VS2008 + SDK7.1 error SHARDAPPIDINFOLINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26631645/compiling-qt-5-3-2-vs2008-sdk7-1-error-shardappidinfolink).
- Per https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/theano-users/JReP5_Ligu4 and [C99 stdint.h header and MS Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/126279/c99-stdint-h-header-and-ms-visual-studio), I copied `stdint.h` from `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include` on another machine, and pasted it into `C:\Qt\qt540\qtwebkit\Source\WTF\wtf`.  I commented out the declaration of `WCHAR_MIN`, and copied that modified stdint.h to `c:\qt\qt540\qtwebkit\source\javascriptcore\runtime`.

With that setup, from the qt5vars.cmd prompt above, I configured Qt with:

> configure -prefix %CD%\qtbase -developer-build -opensource -opengl
>   desktop -nomake tests -no-compile-examples -skip qtwebkit-examples
>   -icu -plugin-sql-sqlite -platform win32-msvc2008 -confirm-license

Then ran `nmake`.  I get a bunch of errors that leveldb can't find stdint.h:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\INCLUDE\xlocale(342) : warning C4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind semantics are not enabled. Sp
ecify /EHsc
C:\Qt\qt540\qtwebkit\Source\ThirdParty\leveldb\db/filename.h(10) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'stdint.h': No such file or directory
c.cc
C:\Qt\qt540\qtwebkit\Source\ThirdParty\leveldb\include\leveldb/c.h(50) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'stdint.h': No such file or directory
dbformat.cc
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\INCLUDE\xlocale(342) : warning C4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind semantics are not enabled. Sp
ecify /EHsc
C:\Qt\qt540\qtwebkit\Source\ThirdParty\leveldb\include\leveldb/db.h(8) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'stdint.h': No such file or directory
db_impl.cc
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\INCLUDE\xlocale(342) : warning C4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind semantics are not enabled. Sp
ecify /EHsc
C:\Qt\qt540\qtwebkit\Source\ThirdParty\leveldb\include\leveldb/db.h(8) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'stdint.h': No such file or directory
db_iter.cc
C:\Qt\qt540\qtwebkit\Source\ThirdParty\leveldb\db/db_iter.h(8) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'stdint.h': No such file or directory
filename.cc
C:\Qt\qt540\qtwebkit\Source\ThirdParty\leveldb\db/filename.h(10) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'stdint.h': No such file or directory
log_reader.cc
C:\Qt\qt540\qtwebkit\Source\ThirdParty\leveldb\db/log_reader.h(8) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'stdint.h': No such file or directory
log_writer.cc
C:\Qt\qt540\qtwebkit\Source\ThirdParty\leveldb\db/log_writer.h(8) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'stdint.h': No such file or directory
memtable.cc
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\INCLUDE\xlocale(342) : warning C4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind semantics are not enabled. Sp
ecify /EHsc
C:\Qt\qt540\qtwebkit\Source\ThirdParty\leveldb\include\leveldb/db.h(8) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'stdint.h': No such file or directory
repair.cc
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\INCLUDE\xlocale(342) : warning C4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind semantics are not enabled. Sp
ecify /EHsc
C:\Qt\qt540\qtwebkit\Source\ThirdParty\leveldb\include\leveldb/db.h(8) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'stdint.h': No such file or directory
table_cache.cc
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\INCLUDE\xlocale(342) : warning C4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind semantics are not enabled. Sp
ecify /EHsc
C:\Qt\qt540\qtwebkit\Source\ThirdParty\leveldb\db/table_cache.h(11) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'stdint.h': No such file or directory
version_edit.cc
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\INCLUDE\xlocale(342) : warning C4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind semantics are not enabled. Sp
ecify /EHsc
C:\Qt\qt540\qtwebkit\Source\ThirdParty\leveldb\include\leveldb/db.h(8) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'stdint.h': No such file or directory
version_set.cc
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\INCLUDE\xlocale(342) : warning C4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind semantics are not enabled. Sp
ecify /EHsc
C:\Qt\qt540\qtwebkit\Source\ThirdParty\leveldb\include\leveldb/db.h(8) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'stdint.h': No such file or directory
write_batch.cc
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\INCLUDE\xlocale(342) : warning C4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind semantics are not enabled. Sp
ecify /EHsc
C:\Qt\qt540\qtwebkit\Source\ThirdParty\leveldb\include\leveldb/db.h(8) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'stdint.h': No such file or directory
Generating Code...
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN\amd64\cl.EXE"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN\amd64\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '(' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cd' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cd' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
```

There is a stdint.h in `C:\Qt\qt540\qtwebkit\Source\ThirdParty\leveldb\port\win`, but copying that file or my modified stdint.h to `leveldb\db` and `leveldb\include\leveldb` makes no difference - I get the same errors when building Qt.

What do I need to do to build qtwebkit with Qt, or at least get past this leveldb sdtint.h issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I'm a dummy.  Just needed to copy `stdint.h` to `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include` instead of to the path of every file that complains.  Additionally, I commented out the declaration of `WCHAR_MIN` in stdint.h to avoid tons of warnings about redeclaring it.

Then using the `configure` statement in the original question, Qt5.4.0 built successfully, including qtwebkit!  Took 11 hours to build, but it worked!